# Field Maps web form - make field visible in all cases but required for only certain previous field domain values

Tags: arcade, arcgis-field-maps

In the Field Maps configurable web form I am trying to make a Notes field visible in all cases but required for only certain previous field domain values.

Use case: For tree monitoring we want staff to be able to make notes on all tree conditions, but if the tree is dead I want to require notes to be made.

Currently, I can add conditional visibility but can not parse out which field values make this field required.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this that seems to work.

You will need to duplicate that field in your form using the [ArcGIS Online Assistant](https://ago-assistant.esri.com/), where it is as easy as copying and pasting the existing JSON snippet next to itself. This can't be done in the smart forms configurator because, as you noticed, once that field is added to the form, it is removed from the list of available fields.

[image: AGOL Assistant Screenshot 1]

After modifying the JSON, you can refresh your map and the smart forms configuration  will have that field listed twice. Make one required and the other one not required. Then set up opposing conditional visibility statements for each.

e.g.

- Required Notes Field statement: $feature.Tree_Condition == 'Dead'
- Optional Notes FIeld statement: $feature.Tree_Condition != 'Dead'

After setting it up, your new JSON will look something like this:

[image: AGOL Assistant Screenshot 2]

**TL;DR: Duplicate the field in your form using the AGOL Assistant. Then make one of them required, set up opposing conditional visibility statements for each.**